# React DOM / React Router DOM - Project Not Rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-dom

I am new to using *react-router-dom*. When I localhost my project, nothing is rendered to either *localhost:3000* or *localhost:3000/home*, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0xHl.png). I am not sure what is causing this issue.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Login from './login.js'
import Home from './home.js'
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

const rounting = (
    <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" Component={Login} />
        <Route path="/home" Component={Home} />
    </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(rounting, document.getElementById('root'));
```

login.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import Home from './home'
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
import { Redirect, Link, Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <div className={styles.App}>
                <div>
                    <p>ABC UNI</p>
                    <p1>Online Testing</p1>
                    <h1>LOGIN</h1>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                    <i className="z"></i>
                </div>

                <div className={styles.inputContainer2}>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />

                    <i class="z"></i>
                    <button>Sign In</button>

                </div>


            </div>
        )
    }

}
export default Login
```

home.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button className={styles.button}>this button</button>
        )
    }
}
export default Home;
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you share your project structure? Also is there any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

The routing needs to be a inside a react functional/class component which you then render like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: yes i change by <login/> but it not render home, i try but it not direct from / to /home , it show localhost/3000/home but still show login page,some thing wrong with my router

Comment: also i didn't notice, you didn't wrap your routes in the <Switch> component

Comment: i don't get it :((, do you have social network or something , please help me out of this, it's 2:21 am now, i find error almost all day, i;m exhausted, thank you so much

Comment: let me install discord brb

Comment: matejko#8235 add me